# One liner for extend loop python

Tags: python

I have the following code lines:

```
records = []

for future in futures:
  records.extends(future.result())
```

each future returns a list.

How can I write the above code but in one liner?

```
records = [future.result() for future in futures]
```

would result in a list inside list.

I have millions of records, i would rather not flat it after creating lists inside list

Comment: Have you tried `records.extends(future.result() for future in futures)`?

Comment: I just got this answer below - but this way I need to declare records = [] in another line. this will make it 2 lines

Comment: @Dejell Don't assume there is always a reasonable one-liner for every loop. I find your original loop slightly clearer than the accepted oneliner (although I wouldn't object to it in a code review).

Comment: @Dejell I updated my answer, check it and see if it works for you, I made a little research and I will apreciate your feedback

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
records = [r for future in futures for r in future.result()]
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this:

1. Use `itertools.chain`:
   `records = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(future.result() for future in futures))`
2. Use the `itertools` consume recipe:
   `records = collections.deque((records.extend(future.result()) for future in futures), maxlen=0)`
3. Use a throw-away list:
   `[records.extend(future.result()) for future in futures]`. `records` will now have all the required content, and you will have temporarily made a list of `None`s

You could also do `functools.reduce(operator.add, (future.result() for future in futures))`, but that wouldn't scale very well

Comment: regarding the third suggestion - I will need to declare records in another line

Comment: Never a great fan of using a list comprehension for side effects. Just use a loop - `[print(x) for x in iterable]` - ugh! Vote for number 1. Doesn't number 2 just discard everything?

Comment: @AChampion: you're right. I was just trying to cover all the bases. Thanks for the bugreport on #2. Fixed now

Comment: @AChampion You were right about the comment in my answer, I edited it to not to make the same mistake again

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Thanks a lot for sharing, that helped me a lot to make a better answer! plus one for ya

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
import functools
records = functools.reduce(lambda res, future: res + future.result()), futures, [])
```

Comment: but then I need to declare records in a different line. that's 2 lines:
records = [] first

Comment: This is an abuse of a list comprehension, using it for the side effect of its expression rather than actually using the list of `None`s it creates.

Comment: @chepner how could I improve it?

Comment: @chepner, do you know a way to return the list inside the lambda?

Comment: If you were going to use `reduce`, you would use it like shown in inspectorG4dget's answer.

Comment: @chepner I think I got it, I have to ask a question my self in this site haaha, but yes, it works just fine :)