# Python: one-line extend within for-loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

### Code:

```
print([some_data[name]['indices'] for name in some_data.keys()])
```

### Output:

```
[[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [2, 1]], [[3, 0], [3, 1], [1, 1], [0, 1]], ...]
```

### Desired Output

```
[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [2, 1], [3, 0], [3, 1], [1, 1], [0, 1], ...]
```

Trying this method told me that the 'list' object has no attribute 'result': [One liner for extend loop python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44442362/one-liner-for-extend-loop-python)

Is there an alteration that I can apply to my code to obtain a one-line solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What would `some_data[name]['indices']` contain? list of atomic values?

Comment: I think You don't need extra `[` and `]` in you `print`

Comment: What is `result` supposed to be? You mention it in the error message but not in your code.

Comment: @Nobilis `some_data[name]['indices']` contains list of lists (length 2): `[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [2, 1]]`, etc

Comment: @mad_ you're right, I had just copied and pasted from where I am actually using it i.e. `if [b, a] not in [some_data[name]['indices'] for name in some_data.keys()]:`

Comment: Try this: `[e for name in some_data.keys() for e in some_data[name]['indices']]`

Comment: @khelwood I don't have a `result`, since I'm not working with futures objects or whatever is being done in the other post

Comment: This should already work as you have it, say you have `d = {'a': {'indices': [0, 0]}, 'b': {'indices': [0, 1]}}`, then calling `[d[i]['indices'] for i in d]` gives you `[[0, 0], [0, 1]]` which is what you want, right?

Comment: @RockyLi That works, if you would like to post as an answer, I'd accept it

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Thought it's more of a comment so it will stay that way.

Answer (score 1):

```
  topList = [[1,2],[3,4]]
  flatList = [item for subList in topList for item in subList]
```

see [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting tge list correctly as single list. 
The print() adds the extra []. Print adds to objects an object type.

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: You are right. Post it by mistake. Cant delete it.

Answer (score 0):

To whoever just deleted their answer using `itertools.chain` - that worked and I was going to accept your answer. The final code:

```
list(itertools.chain(*[some_data[name]['indices'] for name in some_data.keys()]))
```

EDIT: Decided to go without the `itertools` in @Rocky Li's answer:

```
[e for name in some_data.keys() for e in some_data[name]['indices']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? E.g. given:

```py
some_data = {'a': {'indices': [[0, 0], [1, 1]]}, 'b': {'indices': [[2, 2], [3, 3]]}}
```

You want the sublists, right? So we can do:

```
[j for i in some_data for j in some_data[i]['indices']]
```

which returns:

```
[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
```

Comment: Actually `some_data` is in the form `{'Name1': {'indices': [[0, 0], [1, 1]]}, 'Name2': {'indices': [[2, 2], [3, 3]]}}`

Comment: should still be okay, does this not work as it is?

Comment: If it is the same in implementation as @Rocky Li's comment then yes. I just used his because it was already adapted for my use - and worked

Comment: ah, yes, I didn't see that, got beaten to it

Comment: Thank for your help anyway :)